# Pycharm 1.2 Ignoring A Directory Named cvs

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

Am using Pycharm 1.2 on OSX 10.6 . One of my project directories is named cvs, but it is not showing up in the project explorer.  I have tried  uninstalling cvs version control plugin but this didn't resolve it. When i try to manually create the directory , i get a message < trying to create a directory with an ignored name, result will not be visible>  ..  How can i overide this?

Comment: +1 for doing it. A lot of people ignore that suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Settings | File Types | Ignore files and folders, remove CVS from the ignored list.